# If-Else condition does not work as I expect

Tags: sql, if-statement

I have a code that does not seem to have any errors in the writing. The code tries to do joins between tables.

```
exec sel_historiapaciente 1
create proc sel_historiapaciente(
                @idpaciente paciente
)
as
set nocount on

if exists (select * from paciente p
            inner join historiapaciente hp
            on hp.idpaciente = p.idpaciente
            inner join historia h
            on h.idhistoria= hp.idhistoria
            inner join medicoespecialidad me
            on me.idmedico = hp.idmedico
            inner join medico m
            on m.idmedico = me.idmedico
            where p.idpaciente = @idpaciente)
begin
    select * from paciente p
    inner join historiapaciente hp
    on hp.idpaciente = p.idpaciente
    inner join historia h
    on h.idhistoria= hp.idhistoria
    inner join medicoespecialidad me
    on me.idmedico = hp.idmedico
    inner join medico m
    on m.idmedico = me.idmedico
    where p.idpaciente = @idpaciente
end
ELSE
begin
    select 0 as resultado
end
```

As I said above, the code works fine up to this point:

```
ELSE
begin
    select 0 as resultado
end
```

[image]

When idpaciente = 8, I have the result of the first figure, so far there are no problems. But when the number is different from idpaciente = 8, the code should show me a column with the value "0", and what it shows me is this:

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

Add `begin` after the `as` keyword, and an `end` at the very end of the proc definition. In your syntax the proc is just `set nocount on`; it does nothing else.

Comment: I added `begin` and `end` like you said, but still same problem

Comment: When you originally ran the script as shown in your question a proc was created with just 
`set nocount on'. Once you added the `begin...end` as I suggested, and ran the script as is, it first ran the proc (did nothing), then ran the same query as it appears. You might have have been ignoring error messages (like proc already existing).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I changed `CREATE` to `ALTER`, ran `proc` and now it works as it should

Comment: An interesting issue.